# Animation Controller/Scripting in Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2.5D side scroller/platformer project just kind of as a learning experience. I imported a robot model that came with premade animations. I have 2 questions regarding setting him up for movement and his animations. First, I set up movement for x and y, but do I only need to do x? Right now if I hit the UP arrow, the character appears to jump, but feel like that is probably bad form. Am I correct in assuming I should do just the x value for movement and create a separate method for jumping? My second question is with the animation controller. I set up all my states and set my transitions, but I'm not sure what to do from there. What do I do to actually set up the transitions, if anything, and also I could use some information on setting up the animations on the programming side. I have some very slight general knowledge of it, but not much and I'm having trouble finding good solid tutorials for these specific questions.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend doing separate controllers and script files for side to side moving and jumping. That way if you ever need to change one of those behaviours you have a specialized place to do it. Also, perhaps you have an enemy that moves side to side but doesn't jump. Or perhaps something that jumps but doesn't move. You could just drag the correct behaviour onto the game object.

as for animations, the unity learn tutorials are pretty helpful getting you started on animations and very basic state transitions